# Can't apply box shadow inset for input form

Tags: html, css

I want my input form has inset shadow, but it doesn't work. Here my code

```
 #searchopt div input[type='text'],#searchopt div select{
width:220px;height:30px;padding:6px;
/* Overall Layout: box shadow insect*/

-webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 3px 296px -172px rgba(51,39,51,1);

-moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 3px 296px -172px rgba(51,39,51,1);

box-shadow: inset 10px 3px 296px -172px rgba(51,39,51,1);

}
```

However, my overall wrapper div I use shadow as well but outside shadow and it works fine. Here it is

```
/* Overall Layout*/
#wrapper{
margin:0px auto;
border:.5px solid #CCC;
width:1028px;
height:1028px;
overflow:hidden;
font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
/* Overall Layout: box shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);
box-shadow:         0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `border: none;` to the input CSS. That way the input wouldn't use the default, browser specific input style and box-shadow should work

[EDIT] Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AR6m8/. I had to use custom shadow values to see if it works, so your problem might be with the shadow values.

Comment: Thank you! yes it is a value problem, I changed it to `/* Overall Layout: box shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);
box-shadow:         0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);` and it works fine! :)